# PHP form works on index but not contact us page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, submit

I have been developing a pretty simple mailer form in PHP. I have each of the questions in div elements and this javascript reveals the next div/question (it is in the file form.php)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">    
  function hideshow(which){     
  if (!document.getElementById)     
  return    if (which.style.display=="block")
                which.style.display="none"  
  else which.style.display="block"  }
  </script>
```

and a separate code validates what was selected or inputted before revealing the next element.

Okay, so everything works just fine on the index page. However, on the contact us page (where I want the form available since I suspect many people will not fill out the popup on the index page) I have hit a snag. My script advances all the way to the final question and the button to submit the form. Then nothing happens... I can click the button but it does not submit the form. Here is the script that should submit the form (included in validation.js):

```
function ageValidate(){ 'use strict';
    //Verfiy that submitter is not a robot 
    var age=document.getElementById('age').value;
    if(age === ""){     // no answer, submit form
    document.getElementById('ageErr').innerHTML = 'This is to validate that you are not a robot, please enter the correct answer to the problem.';
    return false;
    }   else if (age === "5"){  // right answer
     submitForm();   return true;   }   else {  // wrong answer
    document.getElementById('ageErr').innerHTML = 'Your answer is incorrect or you did not use the numeric format. 2 is valid, but two is not valid.';      }   }

$(document).ready(function() {   $(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }   }); });


function submitForm() {     if (document.getElementsByName("serviceType")[0].value === "")
        return false;   else if (document.getElementsByName("numberPhones")[0].value === "")
        return false;   else if (document.getElementsByName("zip")[0].value === "")
        return false;   else if (document.getElementsByName("email")[0].value === "")
        return false;   else if (document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value === "")
        return false;   else if (document.getElementsByName("age")[0].value === "")
        return false;   else {      document.forms["howHelp"].submit();         }
```

and the last question on the form in form.php:

```
<div id="q7" style="display:none">
    <div class="how-help">
        <h2>What is eight minus three?</h2>
        <center><div>
        <input type="text" name="age" id="age" value="<?php echo $age;?>">      
        </div><br/>
        <div id="ageErr" name="ageErr" style="color: #000;  background: #41b0cc;  font-weight:700;  width: 400px;  height: auto;  margin:0px; font-size:10pt;"></div></center>
    </div>
    <!--   FOOTER  -->
      <div class="how-help-footer">
    <center>
    <input type="button" class="jump"
        value="Continue"
        onclick="ageValidate()"></form>
      </center><a href="javascript:hideshow(document.getElementById('q6')); hideshow(document.getElementById('q7'))" class="back">BACK</a><div class="private"><a href="#" class="private"> Privacy Policy</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script src="validation.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Again, it works perfectly fine on the index page but not the contact page...
I should add that all of the files are in the same directory so there should not be any issue with pointing to the wrong directory. I use

> php include 'form.php'

to have the form both places and I am not sure if this could be the issue, but my form action is:

> $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

I should add that this is an amazing community of extremely helpful people and without the many questions asked and answered I would not be where I am with this project, so thanks for everything in the past and in advance!

Comment: Make sure you have the same IDs on both your index.php and contact.php pages since you are using the same script for both. Also make sure you don't have any conflicting IDs on your contact.php page. You should probably also include your `<form>` code here.

Comment: Please include the `<form>` in its entirety. Also, please include exactly how you're including the `form.php` as `php include 'form.php'`, as-is, will not actually include the form.

Comment: This being my first post I was figuring out how to add code hence the missing parts; however it is on the page as: `<?php include 'form.php' ?>`

Comment: @Bruno You were absolutely right. My contact form that is on that page had a few of the same variables. I didn't even think of that. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Because I was adding the form to a page that already had a comment form on it, the IDs of the two mailers were in conflict. Silly when I pull back and think about it. I've separated the two forms.